# memory leak with swig wrapping std::ios_base::failure into python

Tags: c++, python, exception, swig

I'm using SWIG to wrap a C++ library into both Java and Python. The Java side works fine, but I'm having an issue wrapping the code into Python, in particular when a IO exception is thrown, I get the following in python:

```
...
RuntimeError: _408aad4bde7f0000_p_std__ios_base__failure
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'std::ios_base::failure *', no destructor found.
```

Here is the relevant place in my .i file:

```
%include "exception.i"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
%exception {
    try {
        $action
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_Exception, const_cast<char*>(e.what()));
    }
    catch(std::ios_base::failure &e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IOError, const_cast<char*>(e.what()));
    }
}
```

Any ideas? For what it's worth, the io exceptions work as expected both in native C++ using the library and in SWIG-wrapped Java.

Comment: I think your example interface is missing something - there's no functions that use the `%exception` directive there. Can you reduce the example to the smallest possible interface file and Python code needed to generate the warning?

Comment: Yeah, I cut them out, the whole thing is kinda lengthy. I wrote a simple test from scratch and it seems to be working OK if the C++ code just throws std::ios_base::failure so I've clearly done something wrong somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Probably way too late of an answer, but you're supposed to wrap exceptions like this

```
// http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_stl_exceptions
%exception {
  try {
    $action
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, e.what());
  }
}
```

That is also portable across languages and you don't need separate exception handling for Java and Python.